# My code below gives me a problem, the image comes after the text

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

My code below gives me a problem, the image comes after the text I tryed changing round what goes first but if I place the div.innerhtml near the end I get no images when I load the page. As you can see in the image ive uploaded the Img is being set to the end of the text im also wondering is there a way I can cut the size down?

```
        public partial class UserProfileWall : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
    private void PopulateWallPosts(string userId)
    {

        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=****; Password=****;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Wallpostings FROM WallPosting WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            {
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {


                    var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.ID = "test";
                        div.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
                        img.AlternateText = "Test image";
                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        test1.Controls.Add(div);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }





    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=<REMOVED>; Database=<REMOVED>; User=<REMOVED>; Password=<REMOVED>;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "')", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        PopulateWallPosts(theUserId);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" runat="server" Rows="3" 
        Height="47px" Width="638px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post Message" Width="98px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>

<div id="test1" runat="server" />







</asp:Content>
```

Im trying to achieve this: (crop from paint)
[image]

ignore the web ui parts!

```
div#test1 {
}
#test> img
{
    float: left;
    height: 100px; /* You shouldn't resize images here. Should be done in C#*/
}
#test > div
{
width:90%; 
z-index:1; 
padding:27.5px; 
border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
color:#ffffff;
margin:0 auto;
white-space: pre;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Tryed this to no success?

Snippet from firebug:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_test">weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee<img style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Test image" src="userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your `.aspx` markup please?

Comment: Ive extended the code and the asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any specific reason to inject the divs programmatically? There are databound controls to do the job you are doing. E.g. using Repeater(2.0+) or ListView(3.5+) controls.
[ListView Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Here is a bit complex way see if it helps:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div.Style["float"] = "left";
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
            img.AlternateText = "Test image";
            div.Controls.Add(img);
            test1.Controls.Add(div);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div1.InnerText = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));

            div1.Style["float"] = "left";
            test1.Controls.Add(div1);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div2.Style["clear"] = "both";
            test1.Controls.Add(div2);
```

Surely using css can reduce few lines above.

Comment: this worked but for some reason I couldnt get my css to wrap the text?

Answer (score 3):

1. For the love of God, don't put your passwords inside your post.
2. Do not execute queries purely by string concatenation! Use a [parameterized query](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharpAPI/System.Data.Odbc/OdbcCommandParametersAdd.htm). If I was able to write data to the session, for example with UserId, I could easily inject SQL into this. Please consider using an ORM tool such as NHibernate or Microsoft's Entity Framework.
3. If you want the image to be to the left, with text beside it, use the code [from this link](http://jsfiddle.net/5qBKW/3/) (updated). Essentially on the image you'd want to set the `float` property to be `left`.

If you want to change your code, it could be changed into this:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");

HtmlGenericControl literal = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
literal.InnerHtml = reader.GetString(0);

Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
img.AlternateText = "Test image";
div.Controls.Add(img);
div.Controls.Add(literal);
test1.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: Im learning all the security measures come next Ive heard this over and over again but I would just like to get the functionality in place first be4 I clean up. and its not a new line I need.

Comment: You just beat me to saying the exact same thing. I also edited the connection info (lower down it the code). @Garrith: Also, stick your connection string in the web.config rather than scattering it through your code. You're setting yourself up for a nightmare maintenance scenario.

Comment: @Garrith - Security should be first. If you use an ORM tool, you could easily do all of this without writing a single query.

Comment: Sorry how would I add style="height: 100px; float: left;" /> to a dynamically made div? The img is created everytime the div is created which is set by my code. Please read the cs code I placed in my post for how this works. Not sure I can place such a thing in it?

Comment: @Garrith - See the updated link for a generic way to do this.

Comment: @Garrith - I've adding some more code that would allow you to change it to the same HTML as the sample I provided.

Comment: @Garrith - You should be using `#test1` and not `#test` in the CSS. The id of the div is `test1`, therefore, use `#test1 > img` and `#test1 > div`.

Comment: No, test1 is the container for test the style is added to test not test1 and your code doesnt work, I for some reason its setting to div test1 and not test also you placed the img outside of the div in the code I tryed it your way and tryed to fix it but all im getting is the contents of the database returned under test1 with no image set.

Comment: @Garrith - Ok, you need better id names for the divs. Call the outer one `container` (it was called `test1`). If you have *multiple* child-divs, you can't use the *same id*, which is what you've been doing. The idea of the CSS `>` selector is that it'll find all *child* elements. So, `#container > img` finds all direct children of the element with id `container`.

Comment: sorry its returning now with div test and the comments from the database and each content from the database is in its seperate div but no img is showing even altho firebug shows it there?

Comment: <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_test"><img src="~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg">weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>

Comment: this is working now but not showing? yet if i revert to my original way the img shows?

Comment: @Garrith - Can you post the HTML of the `container` div from firebug?

Comment: nah its not that theres some strange difference between the two codes when i do my code it works but when i use your code it doesnt but its still there im going to screen dump firebug outputs for both maybe then you can see whats happening but I cant debug it atm

Comment: @Garrith - It *is* the `~` because if you use the `Image` control, it resolves the full path of the image. In my old code I provided, it wouldn't resolve that path and therefore the image wouldn't load.

Comment: @Garrith - How about you join me in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c.

Answer (score 0):

Images and text are inline elements, meaning they flow left-to-right.

If you want to force the image to a new line, use the following:

```
div.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}<br />", reader.GetString(0));
```

As for the image size, you need to upload an image that is sized properly, or you can use the Image object in C# to resize it when it is uploaded.

Comment: No I need it to be at the start of the line, not "on" a new line the text has to come after not before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add some CSS to float the image to the left?

```
#test img {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: I already have a div test css how do I add it into that? I will update my post with the css I already have I tryed just adding that to the end of it but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add a ASP:placeholder control to the page instead of a div.  Then in the code behind constuct three divs one for the image, one for the text, and one to contain both of them.

```
//create container
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl container = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");

        //create div to hold the image
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl imgDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        imgDiv.Attributes.Add("class","imgDiv");

        //build the image and set properties.
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = new Unit(60);//pixels
        img.Height = new Unit(60);
        img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

        //add image to image div
        imgDiv.Controls.Add(img);

        //create div to hold text
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl postText = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        postText.Attributes.Add("class", "postText");
        postText.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));

        //now add the two divs to the page
        test1.Controls.Add(imgDiv);
        test1.Controls.Add(postText);
```

Now this should render this in HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="imgDiv">
        //image

    </div>
    <div id="postText">
        //text    
    </div>    
</div>
```

then you can use css to float the text next to the image.

```
.imgDiv{float:left;}
.postText{float:left;}
```

The text will probably jump down to a new line if the window becomes smaller.  You could fix this by setting a minimum width to the container div.

Comment: Actually, you could keep the original div on the asp page and add the img a text divs to that control.  would reduce some of the code.  I tend to like place holders.  Oh and you will probably want to use classes instead of IDs for the CSS since you are looping though multiple posts you will end up with duplicated IDs.